initializer or uninitialized leads different results in C language in case of the same condition
I am writing a program to calculate the remaining amount of the loan after the third installment, but i get different results, the second condition is correct answer, I am unsure whether the use of initialized versus uninitialized variables is causing the discrepancy. How should I modify the program to achieve consistent and correct results?
1.uninitialized condition
enter image description here
enter image description here
2.initializer
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried two conditions, and how should i modify the program to achieve consistent and correct results?

Hi there! Please read about producing a minimal working example so people can help.
